# R: Rearrange specific rows of single-column data frame into new column

Tags: r, dataframe

**EDIT :** Thought it might be useful to mention for anyone searching later that this data is the output I got from [Biomart](http://www.ensembl.org/biomart/martview/8e19bdbc020e4d9439334e6b134ced22) when I tried to output sequence attributes.

I have the following genomic data:

```
structure(list(Sequences = structure(c(2L, 10L, 3L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 
5L, 4L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c(">ENSRNOG00000000902|Hsph1", ">ENSRNOG00000001136|Pebp1", 
">ENSRNOG00000001214|Pfkl", "AGAGAGGCGAGCGGCGGAGAGCGGTGGCAAATACTGAACGCAGTCTCGCAGGGTAAGCCC", 
"GAGCGATTGGGACCTCCCCTTTTGGATTGGTAGCTGAGCGGCAGTGGCGGCGGCTGCGTG", 
"GAGGCATCTTCCCGGCCGGTCGGGAGCAGGAGGAGCACGCAGCGGATCCCAGGCAGAGGC", 
"GGACCGGGCCAGCC", "GGCGGGGACAGGCGACAGCCGCGCGGAACGCAGAGCGGCGGGAGAGGAGCTCGGGCTCCT", 
"GGTCTCTGCTGCCGTC", "GTTTAACTGCACTCGGGACTCGGCGCGCGCGTGTGTCTGTTCTCTCCATCGTC"
), class = "factor")), .Names = "Sequences", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

I would like to rearrange the data so the first column shows the gene ID info (e.g. for the first case it would be: ">ENSRNOG00000001136|Pebp1") and then the lines of genomic code underneath it would appear together in the column next to it. Note that rows 7-10 have multiple lines of genetic code. Here, all the strings below the gene ID info would be concatenated together into one line instead of spread over 4 separate rows. Lastly, I also want to remove the ">" symbol that comes before each of the gene IDs.

The final output would thus be:

```
ID                          Sequence
ENSRNOG00000001136|Pebp1    GTTTAACTGCACTCGGGACTCGGCGCGCGCGTGTGTCTGTTCTCTCCATCGTC
ENSRNOG00000001214|Pfkl GGCGGGGACAGGCGACAGCCGCGCGGAACGCAGAGCGGCGGGAGAGGAGCTCGGGCTCCTGGTCTCTGCTGCCGTC
ENSRNOG00000000902|Hsph1    GAGCGATTGGGACCTCCCCTTTTGGATTGGTAGCTGAGCGGCAGTGGCGGCGGCTGCGTGAGAGAGGCGAGCGGCGGAGAGCGGTGGCAAATACTGAACGCAGTCTCGCAGGGTAAGCCCGAGGCATCTTCCCGGCCGGTCGGGAGCAGGAGGAGCACGCAGCGGATCCCAGGCAGAGGCGGACCGGGCCAGCC
```

Note that this is just the first few lines of ~2500 row data frame. The solution needs to be general enough that it can parse situations where the number of rows taken up by the sequence may be more than the 4 rows shown in the example above.

Comment: Is the ID always of a similar format (i.e. is the ENSRNO part always the same length, and then a pipe symbol delimits it, and then there's another section)?

Comment: Yes. The ID is always of the same format (actually it's "ENSRNO**G**") and length followed by the pipe symbol and the gene name. Same format for all cases.

Comment: And there is never going to be a case where the ID starts on the same row that a genome sequence ended, correct?

Comment: Correct. The IDs are always on a row by themselves separate from the genome sequences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After labeling rows with whether it's a gene name (based on whether it has ">"), you can use `cumsum` to determine groups of the rows. Then you can use `substr` to remove the leading ">" and `tapply` with `paste` to combine all the genes in each group.

```
dat$Sequences <- as.character(dat$Sequences)
(is.gene <- grepl(">", dat$Sequences))
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
(gene.groups <- cumsum(is.gene))
# [1] 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3
data.frame(ID=substr(dat$Sequences[is.gene], 2, nchar(dat$Sequences[is.gene])),
           Sequence=tapply(dat$Sequences[!is.gene], gene.groups[!is.gene], paste, collapse=""))
#                         ID
# 1 ENSRNOG00000001136|Pebp1
# 2  ENSRNOG00000001214|Pfkl
# 3 ENSRNOG00000000902|Hsph1
#                                                                                                                                                                                             Sequence
# 1                                                                                                                                              GTTTAACTGCACTCGGGACTCGGCGCGCGCGTGTGTCTGTTCTCTCCATCGTC
# 2                                                                                                                       GGCGGGGACAGGCGACAGCCGCGCGGAACGCAGAGCGGCGGGAGAGGAGCTCGGGCTCCTGGTCTCTGCTGCCGTC
# 3 GAGCGATTGGGACCTCCCCTTTTGGATTGGTAGCTGAGCGGCAGTGGCGGCGGCTGCGTGAGAGAGGCGAGCGGCGGAGAGCGGTGGCAAATACTGAACGCAGTCTCGCAGGGTAAGCCCGAGGCATCTTCCCGGCCGGTCGGGAGCAGGAGGAGCACGCAGCGGATCCCAGGCAGAGGCGGACCGGGCCAGCC
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible `data.table` solution (though you will have additional column called `indx` that you can remove later if you wish)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(
              ID = sub("^>", "", Sequences[1L]), 
              Sequences = paste(Sequences[-1L], collapse = "")
              ), 
            by = list(indx = cumsum(grepl(">", Sequences)))]
```